# Is FreeBSD's "sh" shell vulnerable to Shellshock?

Tags: freebsd, shellshock

I've got a server for personal use running FreeBSD 10, and it doesn't have Bash installed and never did. However, it comes with the its own POSIX-compliant shell "sh". Do I have to worry about the Shellshock bug on my server?

I tried running this infamous shell script and **didn't** get the "vulnerable" echo, but I don't know if that ensures that I am safe:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' sh -c 'echo hello'
```

Comment: FreeBSD's sh is not the Bourne shell. It's a POSIX shell based on the Almquist shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't know where I read that it's Bourne. I must be wrong. Editing question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are safe (at least against Shellshock). [The "shellshock" bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) is particular to `bash` and doesn't affect the Bourne (traditional `sh`), or Almquist (FreeBSD `sh`, `ash`, Debian's `dash` (and `sh` in newer releases)) or any other non-`bash` shell.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is no problem with the good old shells. Only ppl are too lazy and using bash, even though for the most part they do not really need it. You can configure a ksh or some other to do nearly all the things a bash can. For more advanced uses, ppl should throw a look at zsh, I tried it, and it looks very promising. However, I would never install a powerful shell as a default somewhere or as a shell for an account that is used by the php or webserver user. Such people deserved what they got.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't really answer the question. This could probably do better as a comment.

Comment: I wouldn't call it laziness. I have fond memories of ksh but I haven't used it (other than for nostalgia purposes and only briefly) in well over a decade - I'd say if I used it after 2001 it was no longer than 2002. It's a matter of using the tool that works with you well. Fact is ksh isn't what you expect in Linux installs (by default). And in any event I personally had a bad reaction to C++ and much prefer C; but if I were to say to someone that they're being lazy by using C++ (for a task that you can do with fewer lines than in C) how do you think that'd go? It's not laziness at all.

Comment: More to the point: your suggestion is similar to the old OS wars, editor wars, etc., and they serve no real purpose as far as changing opinions (though the editor war between vi and emacs is very funny). We should all use the tools that we're most comfortable with; not doing so won't help productivity but it might (and might not) hinder it.